# Installing NFS on windows 8 enterprise

Tags: nfs, windows-8

I am having issues installing installing NFS for windows 8. Specifically when i run

```
Ocsetup ServicesForNFS-ServerAndClient;ServerForNFS-Infrastructure;NFS-Administration;ClientForNFS-Infrastructure
```

command i get "The specified windows component could bot be found:"

or if go through "Programs and Features" i get "Windows couldnt complete the requested changes.

Error code: 0x800f0922

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Windows DVD/ISO you can try and install from media instead:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:<FeatureName> /All /Source:E:\Sources\SxS /LimitAccess
```

(where E: is the drive letter of your Windows DVD/ISO)

Comment: I dont know if this fixed it as i can't go back and try it out. But thanks